# Android Fused Location API - how to use PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY and PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY in one application?

Tags: android, permissions, gps, google-play-services, location-client

Android Fused Location API - how to use `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` and `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` in one application?

Hi,
I am developing an applicaiton which need to send periodic location updates. 
I have used Fused Location API with a locaiton pending intent. (update interval 60 seconds and minimumDisplacement 100m). I have registered a locationclient pending intent with `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` and intent service. IntentService was getting called when locaiton changed and this has worked fine for few test drives. But this only works sometimes. When it does not work, I wish to use the `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`

I have noticed that when I use `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`, it gives good locations but the battery usage is quite high. So I have decided to use both `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` and `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` along with ActivityRecognition.

Initially program starts with `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` using LocationPendingIntent and when there is no update for 2 mins, I use LocationListener (and onLocationChanged method) implementing `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` and if there is still no location I call `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`.

The problem I face here is, once this switches to `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`, LocationPendingIntent (which is registered with `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY`) is always using `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` after this. I am removing the location updates at the end of the onLocationChanged method by calling .removeupdates(locationListener); however the GPS icon keeps showing up every minute.

I thought of using static methods for the onLocationChanged method but I understand that this is not good practice for an android app. Also is there any known issues with using PendingIntent and onLocationChanged at the same time? Can you suggest a solution to my problem?

The permissions are set to:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: any news? This describes exactly what I'm experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

(I realise this is a very late response, but having just tackled this, maybe the information benefits someone). I wanted to do something very similar and I had two issues:

- I found removeLocationUpdates failed when I used exactly the same parameters with which I initially requested the updates - that is, I did not get any errors, and the result callback suggested the cancelation had worked OK. But after calling removeLocationUpdates, the location updates just kept happening. I found using parameters 0 and null as in the code here worked for me to stop the updates successfully:

  `Intent selfIntent = new Intent(ACTION_CHECK_LOCATION, null, getApplicationContext(), <ServiceClass>.class);
   PendingIntent selfPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, selfIntent, 0);`
- I may have had a conflict between the calls to requestLocationUpdates and removeLocationUpdates. I didn't want to accidentally stop the updates I'd just requested, so I ended up with two separate classes, one to deal with each type of update.

In my case I did not have a foregrounded app, instead I was using services for background updates. You can see my code here - https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-demos-android/tree/master/2015-DS/LocalGeofence - note that I'm working with another SDK (Esri ArcGIS Runtime for Android SDK, I work for Esri) but you can ignore that bit and just look at two services GeofenceServiceNormal and GeofenceServiceFast, and how they're interacting with the Fused Location API.

I ended up with two service classes (to avoid the requestLocationUpdates and removeLocationUpdates conflict). Each service recognizes when it must change to the other service (see handleActionChangeToFastUpdates and handleActionChangeToNormalUpdates); then it calls removeLocationUpdates for itself, and calls requestLocationUpdates for the other service class. This service worked well for me - maybe you can make use of a similar structure.